# Prototype.js equivalent to jQuery's when()/then()

Tags: promise, prototypejs, deferred

Does prototype.js have an equivalent to jQuery's when() and then()? If not, is there some other recommended way of doing multiple AJAX calls in prototype.js and deferring some action until all have completed?

Comment: Promise.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Prototype maintains a registry of all Ajax calls: http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/

Comment: Prototype.js has been dead for 10 years